# Resampling of a time series multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame of ten different portfolio returns an 12904 days. I am trying to get the rolling covariance matrix for each last day of the month using the past 750 daily returns. I get the daily (EDIT: only business days) covariance matrix with the .rolling() function. Resampling that matrix to take the last value of the daily covariance matrix unfortunately does not return a matrix for each day but rather a single row.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

The DataFrame excess_return (12904 rows × 10 columns):

```
             NoDur  Durbl   Manuf   Enrgy   HiTec   Telcm   Shops   Hlth    Utils   Other
Date                                        
1970-01-02   0.0074 0.0188  0.0111  0.0175  0.0069  0.0162  0.0041  -0.0035 0.0159  0.0175
1970-01-05   0.0058 -0.0023 0.0049  0.0099  0.0066  0.0237  -0.0026 -0.0019 0.0122  0.0052
1970-01-06  -0.0032 -0.0135 -0.0085 -0.0107 -0.0050 -0.0002 0.0015  -0.0047 -0.0105 -0.0111
1970-01-07   0.0012 -0.0047 -0.0004 -0.0080 -0.0000 -0.0015 0.0042  0.0007  -0.0038 -0.0012
1970-01-08  -0.0024 -0.0035 0.0021  -0.0034 0.00255 -0.0057 0.0007  0.0062  0.0015  0.0011
```

The daily rolling covariance matrix:

```
 rolling_cov = excess_return.rolling(750).cov().shift()
```

The code I tried:

```
rolling_cov_monthly = excess_return.rolling(750).cov().shift().groupby([pd.Grouper(level="Date",freq="M")]).last()
```

This did not return an error but does not return the desired output in matrix format.

Another code I tried:

```
rolling_cov.resample("M").last()
```

With the error message:

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'MultiIndex'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about getting the rolling covariance and then filtering just the last business day of the year-month groups:

```
rolling_cov = excess_return.rolling(750).cov()
date_index = rolling_cov.index.get_level_values(0)

last_days = (
    pd.Series(date_index)
    .groupby(date_index.strftime('%Y-%m'))
    .last()
)

rolling_cov[rolling_cov.index.get_level_values(0).isin(last_days)]
```

Comment: That works only if the last day of month is actually included in the dataset. The dataset includes only business days though.

Comment: Would you happen to have a solution at hand that does not show the last day within the dataset but the last day of that month instead? So if the last business day in a month was for example Friday 29th January, the dataframe would show the value of that date but with the 31st january as the date.

Comment: You just need to modify the values of the index, but indexes are immutable objects. Since this is a different topic, ask another question about modifying a multi-index.

Comment: Thanks, I asked a new question here :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67145546/setting-the-datetime-in-a-multiindex-to-last-day-of-the-month